# Cannot make a select on a model alias

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

The hibernate version is 5.2.8.Final

I want to make a select on a model :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Set<Outil> outilsDispoStock(int nbOutils, Achatarticle achatarticle) {
        System.out.println("================ dans DAO....");
        String hql = "select o from Outil o join o.achat c join o.article t join o.statut s where c.idachat = :idachat and t.idarticle = :idarticle and lower(s.nom) = :nom";
        Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
        System.out.println("================ query created....");
        query.setParameter("idachat", achatarticle.getAchat().getIdachat());
        query.setParameter("idarticle", achatarticle.getArticle().getIdarticle());
        query.setParameter("nom", "dispo en stock");
        System.out.println("================ query parameters set....");
        List<Outil> liste = (List<Outil>) query.getResultList();
        System.out.println("================ dans DAO : nb outils dispo stock = "+liste.size());
        return new HashSet<>(liste);
    }
```

But at runtime I get outofmemory exception in tomcat console. When I change the query to `select o.idoutil` for example then the query is executed. So what is wrong ?

**edit :**

here is the model Outil :

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=JSOGGenerator.class)
public class Outil implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idoutil;
    
    @Column(name="codeoutil")
    private java.lang.String code;
    private java.lang.String numeroserie;
    private java.lang.String accessoires;
    private java.lang.String marque;
    private java.lang.String modele;
    private java.lang.String observation;
    private java.lang.String localisation;
    private java.lang.String numeroinventaire;
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private java.util.Date dateinventaire;
    
    @Column(name="prixoutil")
    private double prix;

    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Historiquemouvement
     * assc=historiqueDeMouvementDeL_outil coll=java.util.Set
     * impl=java.util.HashSet mult=0..*
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "outil", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private java.util.Set<Historiquemouvement> historiquemouvement;

    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "outil", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private java.util.Set<Photooutil> photooutil;
    
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Statut assc=employe mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idemploye")
    private Employe employe;
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Statut assc=site mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idsite")
    private Site site;
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Statut assc=statutOutil mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idstatut")
    private Statut statut;
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Etat assc=etat mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idetat")
    private Etat etat;
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Depot assc=estDeposeA mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="iddepot")
    private Depot depot;
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Achat assc=aPourDocumentD_achat mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idachat")
    private Achat achat;
    /**
     * @pdRoleInfo migr=no name=Article assc=articleoutil mult=1..1 side=A
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idarticle")
    private Article article;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idaffectation")
    private Demandemoyen affectation;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idretour")
    private Controleinventaire retour;

    public Outil() {
    }

    public Outil(int idoutil) {
        this.idoutil = idoutil;
    }

    public Outil(int idoutil, String code, String numeroserie, String accessoires, String marque, String modele, String observation, Date dateinventaire, double prix, Employe employe, Site site, Statut statut, Etat etat, Depot depot, Achat achat, Article article) {
        this.idoutil = idoutil;
        this.code = code;
        this.numeroserie = numeroserie;
        this.accessoires = accessoires;
        this.marque = marque;
        this.modele = modele;
        this.observation = observation;
        this.dateinventaire = dateinventaire;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.employe = employe;
        this.site = site;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.depot = depot;
        this.achat = achat;
        this.article = article;
    }
    public Outil(int idoutil, String code, String numeroserie, String accessoires, String marque, String modele, String observation, Date dateinventaire, double prix, Employe employe, Site site, Statut statut, Etat etat, Depot depot, Achat achat, Article article, Demandemoyen affectation, Controleinventaire retour) {
        this.idoutil = idoutil;
        this.code = code;
        this.numeroserie = numeroserie;
        this.accessoires = accessoires;
        this.marque = marque;
        this.modele = modele;
        this.observation = observation;
        this.dateinventaire = dateinventaire;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.employe = employe;
        this.site = site;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.depot = depot;
        this.achat = achat;
        this.article = article;
        this.affectation = affectation;
        this.retour = retour;
    }
    

    public Outil(int idoutil, String code, String numeroserie, String accessoires, String marque, String modele, String observation, String localisation, String numeroinventaire, Date dateinventaire, double prix, Employe employe, Site site, Statut statut, Etat etat, Depot depot, Achat achat, Article article, Demandemoyen affectation, Controleinventaire retour) {
        this.idoutil = idoutil;
        this.code = code;
        this.numeroserie = numeroserie;
        this.accessoires = accessoires;
        this.marque = marque;
        this.modele = modele;
        this.observation = observation;
        this.localisation = localisation;
        this.numeroinventaire = numeroinventaire;
        this.dateinventaire = dateinventaire;
        this.prix = prix;
        this.employe = employe;
        this.site = site;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.etat = etat;
        this.depot = depot;
        this.achat = achat;
        this.article = article;
        this.affectation = affectation;
        this.retour = retour;
    }
    
    

    public int getIdoutil() {
        return idoutil;
    }

    public void setIdoutil(int idoutil) {
        this.idoutil = idoutil;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getNumeroserie() {
        return numeroserie;
    }

    public void setNumeroserie(String numeroserie) {
        this.numeroserie = numeroserie;
    }

    public String getAccessoires() {
        return accessoires;
    }

    public void setAccessoires(String accessoires) {
        this.accessoires = accessoires;
    }

    public String getMarque() {
        return marque;
    }

    public void setMarque(String marque) {
        this.marque = marque;
    }

    public String getModele() {
        return modele;
    }

    public void setModele(String modele) {
        this.modele = modele;
    }

    public String getObservation() {
        return observation;
    }

    public void setObservation(String observation) {
        this.observation = observation;
    }
    
    public Date getDateinventaire() {
        return dateinventaire;
    }

    public void setDateinventaire(Date dateinventaire) {
        this.dateinventaire = dateinventaire;
    }

    public double getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }

    public void setPrix(double prix) {
        this.prix = prix;
    }

    public String getLocalisation() {
        return localisation;
    }

    public void setLocalisation(String localisation) {
        this.localisation = localisation;
    }

    public String getNumeroinventaire() {
        return numeroinventaire;
    }

    public void setNumeroinventaire(String numeroinventaire) {
        this.numeroinventaire = numeroinventaire;
    }

    
    
    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default getter
     */
    public java.util.Set<Historiquemouvement> getHistoriquemouvement() {
        if (historiquemouvement == null) {
            historiquemouvement = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        }
        return historiquemouvement;
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default iterator getter
     */
    public java.util.Iterator getIteratorHistoriquemouvement() {
        if (historiquemouvement == null) {
            historiquemouvement = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        }
        return historiquemouvement.iterator();
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default setter
     * @param newHistoriquemouvement
     */
    public void setHistoriquemouvement(java.util.Set<Historiquemouvement> newHistoriquemouvement) {
        removeAllHistoriquemouvement();
        for (java.util.Iterator iter = newHistoriquemouvement.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            addHistoriquemouvement((Historiquemouvement) iter.next());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default add
     * @param newHistoriquemouvement
     */
    public void addHistoriquemouvement(Historiquemouvement newHistoriquemouvement) {
        if (newHistoriquemouvement == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.historiquemouvement == null) {
            this.historiquemouvement = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        }
        if (!this.historiquemouvement.contains(newHistoriquemouvement)) {
            this.historiquemouvement.add(newHistoriquemouvement);
            newHistoriquemouvement.setOutil(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default remove
     * @param oldHistoriquemouvement
     */
    public void removeHistoriquemouvement(Historiquemouvement oldHistoriquemouvement) {
        if (oldHistoriquemouvement == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.historiquemouvement != null) {
            if (this.historiquemouvement.contains(oldHistoriquemouvement)) {
                this.historiquemouvement.remove(oldHistoriquemouvement);
                oldHistoriquemouvement.setOutil((Outil) null);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default removeAll
     */
    public void removeAllHistoriquemouvement() {
        if (historiquemouvement != null) {
            Historiquemouvement oldHistoriquemouvement;
            for (java.util.Iterator iter = getIteratorHistoriquemouvement(); iter.hasNext();) {
                oldHistoriquemouvement = (Historiquemouvement) iter.next();
                iter.remove();
                oldHistoriquemouvement.setOutil((Outil) null);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Statut getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newStatut
     */
    public void setStatut(Statut newStatut) {
        if (this.statut == null || !this.statut.equals(newStatut)) {
            if (this.statut != null) {
                this.statut = null;
            }
            if (newStatut != null) {
                this.statut = newStatut;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Etat getEtat() {
        return etat;
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newEtat
     */
    public void setEtat(Etat newEtat) {
        if (this.etat == null || !this.etat.equals(newEtat)) {
            if (this.etat != null) {
                this.etat = null;
            }
            if (newEtat != null) {
                this.etat = newEtat;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Depot getDepot() {
        return depot;
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newDepot
     */
    public void setDepot(Depot newDepot) {
        if (this.depot == null || !this.depot.equals(newDepot)) {
            if (this.depot != null) {
                this.depot = null;
            }
            if (newDepot != null) {
                this.depot = newDepot;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Employe getEmploye() {
        return employe;
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newEmploye
     */
    public void setEmploye(Employe newEmploye) {
        if (this.employe == null || !this.employe.equals(newEmploye)) {
            if (this.employe != null) {
                Employe oldEmploye = this.employe;
                this.employe = null;
                oldEmploye.removeOutil(this);
            }
            if (newEmploye != null) {
                this.employe = newEmploye;
                this.employe.addOutil(this);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Achat getAchat() {
        return achat;
    }
    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newAchat
     */
    public void setAchat(Achat newAchat) {
        if (this.achat == null || !this.achat.equals(newAchat)) {
            if (this.achat != null) {
                Achat oldAchat = this.achat;
                this.achat = null;
                oldAchat.removeOutil(this);
            }
            if (newAchat != null) {
                this.achat = newAchat;
                this.achat.addOutil(this);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Article getArticle() {
        return article;
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newArticle
     */
    public void setArticle(Article newArticle) {
        if (this.article == null || !this.article.equals(newArticle)) {
            if (this.article != null) {
                Article oldArticle = this.article;
                this.article = null;
                oldArticle.removeOutil(this);
            }
            if (newArticle != null) {
                this.article = newArticle;
                this.article.addOutil(this);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default parent getter
     */
    public Site getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default parent setter
     * @param newSite
     */
    public void setSite(Site newSite) {
        if (this.site == null || !this.site.equals(newSite)) {
            if (this.site != null) {
                Site oldSite = this.site;
                this.site = null;
                oldSite.removeOutil(this);
            }
            if (newSite != null) {
                this.site = newSite;
                this.site.addOutil(this);
            }
        }
    }

    public Demandemoyen getAffectation() {
        return affectation;
    }

    public void setAffectation(Demandemoyen affectation) {
        this.affectation = affectation;
    }

    public Controleinventaire getRetour() {
        return retour;
    }

    public void setRetour(Controleinventaire retour) {
        this.retour = retour;
    }
    
    
    
    /******** PHOTO OUTIL *******/
    
    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default getter
     */
    public java.util.Set<Photooutil> getPhotooutil() {
        if (photooutil == null) {
            photooutil = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        }
        return photooutil;
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     * @pdGenerated default iterator getter
     */
    public java.util.Iterator getIteratorPhotooutil() {
        if (photooutil == null) {
            photooutil = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        }
        return photooutil.iterator();
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default setter
     * @param newPhotooutil
     */
    public void setPhotooutil(java.util.Set<Photooutil> newPhotooutil) {
        removeAllPhotooutil();
        for (java.util.Iterator iter = newPhotooutil.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            addPhotooutil((Photooutil) iter.next());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default add
     * @param newPhotooutil
     */
    public void addPhotooutil(Photooutil newPhotooutil) {
        if (newPhotooutil == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.photooutil == null) {
            this.photooutil = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        }
        if (!this.photooutil.contains(newPhotooutil)) {
            this.photooutil.add(newPhotooutil);
            newPhotooutil.setOutil(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default remove
     * @param oldPhotooutil
     */
    public void removePhotooutil(Photooutil oldPhotooutil) {
        if (oldPhotooutil == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.photooutil != null) {
            if (this.photooutil.contains(oldPhotooutil)) {
                this.photooutil.remove(oldPhotooutil);
                oldPhotooutil.setOutil((Outil) null);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @pdGenerated default removeAll
     */
    public void removeAllPhotooutil() {
        if (photooutil != null) {
            Photooutil oldPhotooutil;
            for (java.util.Iterator iter = getIteratorPhotooutil(); iter.hasNext();) {
                oldPhotooutil = (Photooutil) iter.next();
                iter.remove();
                oldPhotooutil.setOutil((Outil) null);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Lombok?

Comment: no, there is no Lombok dependency

Comment: Have you implemented toString or equals and hashCode

Comment: where are them to be located ?

Comment: If you use HasSet, you must implement equals and hashCode

Comment: Can you please show the class Outil

Comment: I included the class Outil in the post

Answer (score 1):

With your explicit usage of `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` and the same being the case implicitly for `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne`, you are essentially loading all object that are reachable through this model, which will, depending on the data, trigger quite a lot of queries and hence load a lot of data. My guess is, you are loading the whole database and this will require more memory than your application has available.

I suggest you remove the `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` from all `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToMany` associations and also rethink how you define your `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` associations, as I think you should always strive to use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, since you can control fetching with entity graphs or just let lazy loading do its thing.